# Data is persisting on an old view when new information should be on it - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having a really interesting issue when selecting a `UITableViewCell`. At the moment I'm trying to pass an array from my main ViewController into a secondary ViewController. The first time I launch my app and select a cell within my `UITableView` everything loads perfectly, however the second time when I select a different cell, the information from the old cell seems to persist until I got back once again and choose the cell a second time.

Here are the functions that handle the information passover in my first ViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row
    print("The current row is: ", self.selectedRow)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let nextViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedEventViewController

    nextViewController.recievedArray = [self.eventArrayData[self.selectedRow]]
}
```

and this is the view controller that's receiving the information

```
class SelectedEventViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var recHost: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recAddress: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recTown: UILabel!

    var recievedArray: Array = [eventStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.loadData()
    }

    func loadData()
    {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.recievedArray[0].eventLat, longitude: self.recievedArray[0].eventLong, zoom: 15)
        self.mapView.camera = camera

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
        marker.title = self.recievedArray[0].eventHost
        marker.map = self.mapView

        recHost.text = self.recievedArray[0].eventHost

        self.title = self.recievedArray[0].eventHost
    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are triggering the segue directly from the `action` outlet for the row in the storyboard with the result that the segue is being initiated before the `didSelectRowAt` function is called with the result that `self.selectedRow` contains the old row when `prepare(for:)` is called.

You can use the `indexPathForSelectedRow` property in your `prepare(for:)` and then you don't need to implement `didSelectRowAt:`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let nextViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedEventViewController
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        nextViewController.recievedArray = [self.eventArrayData[selectedRow]]
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried out the code suggested and I appear to be receiving a "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'"

Comment: You probably have an error in your balancing of { }

Comment: Just checked but nothing appears to be off with the balancing of  { }

Comment: Well, nothing in the code I have references `numberOfRowsInSection` so, you have a problem somewhere and that error message is typically caused by a {} problem or something similar

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding the `self` in front of the tableView because the `@IBOutlet` was stored in my class and not the function. Now I appear to be getting a new error when I try to select a cell in my table `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: That means that `self.tableview` is `nil`; check that you have connected the outlet properly.